# Hashing names to string

Tags: ruby, hash

I have addresses like

1. 12th Park Street - Residential
2. 11th Industrial Estate - Unclassified

I want  to convert them to hexadeciaml hashes like `"9naida990"`, with some length k (9 here), for unique identification of each one of them.

Is there any way of doing that, or is there any ruby gem that already implements that?

Comment: What is "9naida990"?

Comment: A random hexadecimal string of specified length.

Comment: I think the question can be further clarified

Comment: @SagarGrover a hexadecimal string containing `n` and `i`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like a `Digest`?

```
>> require 'Digest'
=> true
>> x = "12th Park Street - Residential"
=> "12th Park Street - Residential"
>> Digest::MD5.hexdigest(x)[0..9]
=> "c68636e164"
>> Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(x)[0..9]
=> "e3d93a448b"
```

Should be relatively unique at 9 chars, but could use the full digest as well. to make it even more unique.

```
>> Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(x)
=> "e3d93a448baa56cc7bdbf896fa32c827350592cc"
>> Digest::MD5.hexdigest(x)
=> "c68636e164b08d037b77d0d5768095d0"
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I was looking for. Thanks